# My dog was attacked by an owl

Tags: dogs, behavior, psychology, fear

My pet chihuahua was attacked by an owl and we took her to the vet. She was just bruised, but I just want to know how do you get your puppy back to normal self, because my dog hasn’t acted her normal self again ever since. She’s isn’t playful, she does’t wag her tail because of how traumatized she is.

I’m wondering how can you get your puppy back to normal. I miss her being herself and it hurts me so much.